# Return a creature with an adventure to hand, can i cast the instant/sorcery again?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-adventure-cards

Will returning [Brazen Borrower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrazen%20Borrower%5d) from the battlefield to my hand using the -3 ability of [Teferi, Time Raveler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Time%20Raveler%5d) enable me to cast [Petty Theft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPetty%20Theft%5d) again?

The rulings say nothing against it but I have the feeling that this would be kind of broken. But on the other hand you don't remember something like a "card state" I guess.

Comment: What do you mean "cast Petty Theft again"? If you had cast Petty Theft, it wouldn't be on the battlefield. If you mean cast Petty Theft, then cast it as Brazen Borrower from exile, then return it to your hand, then cast it as Petty Theft, how is that broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you would be able to use the adventure again.**

If an object changes zones (like battlefield, hand, library, graveyard and exile) it is a completely new object and knows nothing about anything that happened to "it" (the card that represents it) before. So you can send everything off on an adventure again. But you are right, for that you have to have played the creature part of the adventure and then return it to hand. Before that the card is in exile (and thus hard to interact with).

Comment: almost thought so. Thats why i cant find any rulings for it.

Comment: but there is just nothing to be (specifically) ruled in my opinion. 1. the creature is on the battlefield and thus can be returned to hand with such effects. 2. a creature that has an adventure-half can be cast as the "adventure" portion from the hand.
those two points are unrelated and don't influence each other.